# Nginx - rewrite query string to path

Tags: nginx, rewrite

My attempt at defining a nginx query string path rewrite is failing so far. Am getting **502 Bad Gateway**. Looking for any obvious errors.

Trying to achieve the following:

before
https://example.co.uk/user/username?profiletab=products

after
https://example.co.uk/user/username/products

The 'username' would of course always change per user.

I'm using generators and all sorts to try build this, I am no regex type of person etc.

```
location ~ "/user/([^/]+)/products" {
  try_files $uri /user/$1?profiletab=products;
}
```

Attempt #2

```
location ~ "^/user/([^/]+)/products(/?)$" {
  set $products_user "$1";
  try_files $uri $uri/ @products;
}

location @products {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/user/$products_user/?profiletab=products;
}
```

Comment: Any reason to use `try_files`? Do you expect a file named `/user/username/products` to exist?

Comment: No, tbh this is the generator working for me, I am simply a wordpress developer trying to figure this out ha. I'll try look at what try_files is some more.

Comment: Show full server block that works now

Comment: I have no existing rewrites etc currently. Simply trying to override the url generated by a membership plugin.

Answer (score -1):

You want to rewrite one "SEO" URL to another (SEO->SEO), and `try_files` is for locating actual files to use for serving a request (SEO->file). So it's not what you need here.

What you need is rewriting internal URL, which is where `rewrite` shines.

```
server {
    # SEO->SEO:
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/products/?$ /user/$1/products?profiletab=products;
    # your existing Wordpress block (SEO->file)
    location / {
        try_files ...
    }
}
```

The `^/user/([^/]+)/products/?$` mathes strings like `/user/username/products` and captures username part to be available in `$1` for the second argument to `rewrite`.